# How to ban specific file(s) from windows 7(ultimate)?

Tags: windows-7

I want to ban a file (adware) from my computer. Whenever I delete the file, it automatically downloads from internet.So there is no option but to somehow ban this file.
Is there any way I can ban a file in windows 7 ?

Comment: Probably not going to happen. Instead, find out what keeps downloading it and remove that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isnt the file, its the malware. Obviously, the malware is downloading the file, but deleting the file isnt resolving the issue, as it is somewhere else in your system.

I recommend [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) AntiMalware.  It is very good at getting rid of unwanted malware.

For further info on cleaning malware out of your system, perhaps check out this common SU question: [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Can we delete a malware manually ?